# Why is options menu not showing up in my app?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

i set up an option menu in my android app but its not showing up
here's the code

```html
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">
        
        //there are some views the toolbar
        //also note i change the theme to android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

and heres is the menu

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
    android:title="Search"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/findFriends"
    android:title="Find Users"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_person_add"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>



<item
    android:id="@+id/settings"
    android:title="Settings"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/log_out"
    android:title="Log Out"
    />

<item
    android:id="@+id/exit"
    android:title="Exit"
    />
```

and here is the code

```js
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
        val inflater = menuInflater
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu)

        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

        when(item.itemId){
            id.app_bar_search ->{
                //donothing for now
            }
            id.exit -> super.onBackPressed()

            id.settings -> {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Settings clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show()
            }
            id.findFriends ->{
                val intent = Intent(this, UsersActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
            id.log_out ->{
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()
                val intent = Intent(this, LoginActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
```

i still don't know why this isn't showing up can someone help me out please?
ihave followed alot of tuturials and this is how they set up the options menu but i cant figure out why it isnt working..

Answer (score 2):

In your Activity code, you should call

```
setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar))
```

in `onCreate()` after your `setContentView(...)` method, so that your Toolbar will act as an ActionBar and this will enable its menu.

Comment: Thanks. it worked but it showing the ap name which i dont want

Comment: It's the default behaviour, but you can disable it by adding `supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)`

Answer (score 1):

**The Easiest Way to add and display Options Menu using Kotlin**

**my_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item
      android:id="@+id/newMenu"
      android:title="New"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/saveMenu"
        android:title="Save"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">

    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/saveasMenu"
        android:title="Save Us"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/editMenu"
        android:title="Edit"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/exitMenu"
        android:title="Exit"/>
    </menu>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/myToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#BDAADF"
        style="@style/Base.Theme.Menu"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Options Menu"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
package com.example.menu

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuInflater
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.widget.Toast
import android.widget.Toolbar

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.myToolbar))
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)
    }

    //Attach xml menu file (my_menu.xml) to Main Activity
    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        val inflater: MenuInflater = menuInflater
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu,menu)
        return true
    }
    //Menu Item event
    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when(item.itemId)
        {
            R.id.newMenu -> Toast.makeText(this,"New is clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            R.id.saveMenu -> Toast.makeText(this,"Save is clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            R.id.saveasMenu -> Toast.makeText(this,"Save As is clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            R.id.editMenu -> Toast.makeText(this,"Edit is clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            R.id.exitMenu -> Toast.makeText(this,"Exit is clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Toolbar` as `ActionBar`:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.xxxx)
    setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.toolbar))
    supportActionBar?.setTitle("")
}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu)
    return true
}
```

Or you can use:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.xxx)
    val toolbar : Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
    toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.toolbar_menu)
}
```